# Why are "echo" short tags permanently enabled as of PHP 5.4?

Tags: php, coding-style, php-shorttags

Even the official documentation used to tell us that [PHP "short tags" (`<? /*...*/ ?>`) are "bad"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use). However, [since PHP 5.4, the `echo` variety `<?= /*...*/ ?>` is permanently enabled regardless of the `short_open_tag` setting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

*What's changed?*

Even if they were previously discouraged solely due to the unpredictable nature of whether `short_open_tag` is enabled on a shared hosting platform, surely that argument doesn't go away just because some subset of hosts will be running PHP 5.4?

Arguably this change to the language doesn't inherently signify a change in the recommendation that we should nonetheless avoid "short tags", but if they've gone to the trouble it would certainly seem like the PHP devs no longer "hate" them so much. Right?

*The only logical conclusion I can draw at this time is that there must be some objective rationale for the introduction of this change in PHP 5.4.*

*What is it?*

Comment: If I read http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php correctly, your question isn't quite correct - `<?=` (short-tag echo) is always enabled, but other short tag usages aren't (untested).  Still, I'd be interested to know the reasoning for that change as well.

Comment: You mean "short echo tag <?= is always recognized and valid"? That's just used for echo and they are permanently enabled, AFAIK

Comment: That's not what it says. All it says is the `<?=` which is equivalent to `<?php echo ...?>` is always available.

Comment: The original reasoning for introducing the config option for short tags was that some sheople had the unsuppressible urge to mix PHP into XML files, where `<?` clashed with `<?xml`. Now it was uncovered that most XML editors that people appearantly use for editing PHP files don't bail when encountering `<?=` or so.

Comment: @mario that would make sense, do you have a link to a relevant dev mailing list discussion or similar?

Comment: Indeed that would make the perfect answer were a citation available

Comment: Gark, is there a searchable dev mailing list anyway?  http://news.php.net/ seems to have an overzealous robots.txt :(

Comment: Here's the RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortags , which seems to confirm what @mario says.

Comment: @therefromhere Don't remember where I read it. Similar topic on Progrmmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php And the `<?=` is not actually a valid syntax for [XML processing instructions](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi), but was considered less conflicting (probably because it's widely recognized) than the short open `<?` token.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Short open tags** are not always enabled since PHP 5.4. The documentation talks about the **short echo tags**. Which is a different thing. (short open tags are `<?` style tags, short echo tags are `<?=` style tags, for echo-ing).

Then why are they enabled by default now? Well, there are a lot of scripts out there, where it benefits to use `<?= $somevar ?>` instead of `<?php echo $somevar ?>`. And [because the short echo tags aren't as bad as the short open tags, they chose to always enable the short echo tags](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortags). Because now developers (of frameworks and CMS-es) can count on them (or rather, when PHP 5.4 becomes mainstream).

However, the short **open** tags are still influenced by the `short_open_tag` setting in your php.ini.

Comment: Well, giving the same behavior on all installations is a good thing. The more options we have the more things one has to mind. The thing here is that in templates the short echo is nice, but short open tags cause conflicts with XML processing instructions (think <?xml, <?xsl, ...) , so we added higher comfort for portable code ... I hope that explains the sense of the design decision in this case -Johannes (PHP Development Team Member)

Comment: @johannes: It's not "all" installations though. By releasing a new version you by definition add a new option that not everybody will have, despite the best intentions ([for example](http://xkcd.com/927/)). Was this something that was raised within the dev team during the discussions leading up to the feature change?

Comment: Well, we can't change the past. We can try to improve for the future, though. At least as much as legacy allows ...

Comment: But maybe somebody can borrow his time machine, there are quite some things in PHP I really would love to change from the start which can't be made undone none

Comment: Accepted after adding citation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's the best sarcastic comment I've ever read on SO (me here not being sarcastic)

Comment: @GustavoRubio: It wasn't sarcastic

Answer (score 5):

Only short echo tag (`<?=`) is enabled permanently, not short open tags (`<?`). 
It's because short echo tag is really handy when you're creating HTML templates (or any other view templates) and without that you have to write a lot more (like `<?php echo $var; ?>` instead of just `<?= $var ?>`).

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Starting with PHP 5.4, short echo tag **`<?=`** is always recognized and valid, regardless of the short_open_tag setting.

All that this is saying, is that `<?=` is always valid, and not `<?`

Comment: Yes, but the question is _why_.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `< ?` is used in XML documents and enabling short_open_tags will generate errors in XML codes.
But, `< ?=`, just like `< ?php` is not XML open tag and is safe to use.