# Is <? ... ?> valid shorthand PHP and will it always work?

Tags: php, shorthand

I sort of discovered by accident that

```
<?php ... ?>
```

can be shortened to

```
<? ... ?>
```

Is this a bad idea? In some cases? What cases are they? Are there anymore shorthand examples? I am aware of shorthand examples involving conditional statements but I don't find them easier to read.

Please link me if this has been answered elsewhere, but I could not find it via a search. Maybe I'm not using the right keywords.

Comment: IMHO avoid them as this will confuse folks with XML

Comment: I've never understood the use of short tags; the additional three keystrokes aren't really *that* much of a problem; and using short tags seems to risk unnecessary problems.

Comment: I concur with @DavidThomas. They are the hallmark of the lazy, in my experience. I rather _like_ that a PHP block starts with the text `php`. It's hard to misunderstand your code when it's so clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shorthand has been available for a very long time, but [its use is discouraged](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) (and nowadays disabled by default) because of various incompatibilities with other languages — ambiguity with ASP's ability to accept `<? x ?>`, and with various XML constructions, are two obvious examples.

**Opt not to use it.**

By contrast, the `<?= x ?>` shorthand (equivalent to `<?php echo x ?>`) has had a resurgence in popularity and [is enabled by default since PHP 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14188397/560648), because it does not suffer from the same problems.

*As always, consult the documentation for canonical information on such things.*

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Great answer and left me with some ref URL's to further reading, which led me to this. What is the case scenario where  somebody would use <script language="php"></script>?

Comment: @DanielSchwarz: We don't talk about that :P

Comment: Haha, I figured as much, it was an interesting find though!

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand tags are only enabled in certain setups. They are discouraged. See the PHP manual entry for the tags: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

> PHP also allows for short open tags  (which are discouraged because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option.

As far as other shorthands, no others exist. The `<?= ?>` shorthand could possibly be considered one, though it's only usage is to output a variable (as mentioned in another answer to this question). The omission of the closing `?>` is sort-of one. It's handy for documents that contain nothing beyond PHP code. This technique is also mentioned in the manual entry I linked above.

Comment: `<?= x ?>` certainly exists.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is it PHP-specific though?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that one @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it's really useful for inserting between HTML, thanks!

Comment: @blakeo_x: Yes, which is why it does not suffer from the same problems and has been enabled by default since PHP 5.4.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit interesting. I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Will it work? In some cases. PHP has a few opening tags available, take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php). But you should be careful as it depends on the php configuration (usually /etc/php.ini or /etc/php/php.ini). There is an option `short_open_tag = On`. if it's not enabled, the code will be rendered in the view and won't be executed as php code.

Answer (score 0):

As blakeo_x said, the shorthand is only valid if the PHP configuration file has it enabled. 
It is discouraged because you might have to run it on a different server where shorthand is not enabled. Hence try to stick to the longer version `<?php` instead.