# Strange ERROR: Same PHP code but different result in mac and windows machine

Tags: php, windows, macos, xampp

I have met a very strange bug. Given the same piece of code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])): ?>
<p><a href="admin_reg.php">Regsiter as admin</p>
<p><a href="student_reg.php">Register as student</p>
<p><a href="login.php">Log in</a></p>
<? else: ?>
<p><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></p>
<p><a href="group_create.php">Create group</a></p>
<p><a href="group_join.php">Join group</a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My group mates and I run the same project on different machines (they use windows and I use mac). We all run it in the xampp and I get a normal result: Before authentication, just the first three links appear. But in their machines, all six links have shown on the page, which is impossible. Our PHP version are also the same: `5.6.1*`. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all 6 display then PHP isn't installed/configured correctly or the page doesn't have a `.php` extension.  Do a view source on the page and you will see the PHP code.

Comment: Perhaps short tags aren't enabled on their servers. The else line is the only one that has `<?` instead of `<?php`

Comment: @aynber: Good catch!

Comment: your else is using short tags and it must be enabled to work properly. Try changing to full tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your else is using short tags, which may not be enabled on all servers. Change it to use the full php tag:

```
<?php else: ?>
```

Comment: Great detective work on your part, however this part of your question *"which does not work on all servers"* perplexes me. That option can be enabled in their system files. As this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/14188397/ outlines that the `<?` are not enabled by default, the `<?=` is enabled permanently. Just a quick note about that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As **aynber** pointed out, it is most likely due to your short tag that must be enabled in the php.ini.

But why not write your code like so? Fully compatible, regardless of php configuration.

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    echo '<p><a href="admin_reg.php">Regsiter as admin</p>',
         '<p><a href="student_reg.php">Register as student</p>',
         '<p><a href="admin_reg.php">Regsiter as admin</p>';
  } else {
    echo '<p><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></p>',
         '<p><a href="group_create.php">Create group</a></p>',
         '<p><a href="group_join.php">Join group</a></p>';
  }

?>
```

It is also worth mentioning that *the same* php code can have different results on different operating systems (apart from the server settings). In Linux a DB is case sensitive, in Windows it is not. Path locations should also be taken into account. Then there is the 32b vs 64b integer size, just saying it is not an uncommon issue.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php *"7.0.0 The ASP tags <%, %>, <%=, and the script tag <script language="php"> are removed from PHP."* - There's no mention in there about `<?` - They specifically wrote *"The ASP tags"*. I'm not saying you're wrong here, but I'm not saying you're right neither.

Comment: I personally prefer "template" syntax over echo when using mixed html and php.  Using echo removes the ability to easily use `"` double quotes and you'd be better off using a NewDoc or HereDoc instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right, as it has nothing to do with the issue at hand I removed the line.

Comment: @Xorifelse Thanks. I did have another thought as I was getting myself another cup of coffee *(lol)*. If PHP 7.0 ever dropped `<?` short tags, there'd be a lot of ticked off (PHP) coders having to completely rebuild their code if/when they upgraded ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, its's not like their not ticked off already with all those legacy database connections... :)

Comment: @Xorifelse *haha!* - You have a point there. But that's a totally different animal though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code bellow:

```php
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){ ?>
<p><a href="admin_reg.php">Regsiter as admin</p>
<p><a href="student_reg.php">Register as student</p>
<p><a href="login.php">Log in</a></p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></p>
<p><a href="group_create.php">Create group</a></p>
<p><a href="group_join.php">Join group</a></p>
<?php } ?>
```