# PHP Short Open Tag prints "1 "

Tags: php

When i write php code with html using php short open tag, it prints 1 every time.

```
<?= include_once 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

Why it's happening ?

Comment: You are following wrong syntax for include file.<?= is short form of <?php echo which is not needed for file include

try <? include_once 'includes/footer.php'; ?>

Comment: Don't use PHP short tags, they are not recommended.

Comment: _Do use_ **short echo** (`<?= ... ?>`) tags when using PHP for templating i.e. embedded in HTML or whatever you are outputting as text. _It is recommended and is always available_ in PHP 5.4 and later. It is a lot easier than using `<?php echo `. maybe interesting? [Why are “echo” short tags permanently enabled as of PHP 5.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188397/why-are-echo-short-tags-permanently-enabled-as-of-php-5-4)

Comment: @RyanVincent I used (<?php ?>) tag for everything. But i have decided to use (<?=  ?>) tag for printing from  the next time. Thanks for your valuable advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it returns **true**. You need to use `include_once` without the short open tag, so like this:

```
<?php include_once 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

When you write an open short tag, like this;

```
<?= include_once 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

You actually write this:

```
<?php echo include_once 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

Which results in "1" on your screen.

Answer (score 2):

Php Short Tag is used to echo the variable not for including the file

```
<?= ?> (echo short tags)
```

See this http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 1):

Because include_once return **TRUE**, so if you print it it will display `"1"`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `=` sign and try. In short tags `=` used for echo and since you're including the file without any problem it returns 1 and it will be echoed back.