# odd even colored rows into a repeat region

Tags: php, html, css

I try to make it work into the repeat region but it doesn't work.

```
<body>
<?php do { ?>
<table class="test">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['fld1']; ?></td>
<td>...</td>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['fld2']; ?></td>
<td>...</td>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['fld3']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</body>
```

and the style is

```
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
.test tr:nth-child(even) {background: #A4D1FF;}
.test tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #F2F2F2;}
</style>
</head>
```

---

Actually the dynamically table generates more than 50 rows so it needs to be into the PHP loop...
The full page code is but it still doesn't work ...
thank's all for your answers...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type = "test">
.test tr:nth-child(even) { 
    background: #A4D1FF;
}
.test tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #EAF4FF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="test">
<?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['movies']; ?></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['et_paragogis']; ?></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['format']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
  </table>  
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: you want to use style for each td or tr ??

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: Take the `<table>` tags outside of the PHP loop. You should only be generating one set of `<table>` tags at the start and end of the table, not for every row. Once you do this, your CSS stands a chance of working.

Answer (score 1):

if you put your `table` out of the PHP loop (`<?php do { ?>`) you will get something like this

```css
.test tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F2F2F2;
}
.test tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #A4D1FF;
}
```

```html
<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>
      odd
    </td>
    <td>odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      even
    </td>
    <td>
      even
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the `<table>` tag outside of the do-while loop.

```
<body>
    <table class="test">
        <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row_Recordset1['fld1']; ?></td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><?= $row_Recordset1['fld2']; ?></td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><?= $row_Recordset1['fld3']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

N.B. Try to use `<?= ?>` instead of `<?php  ?>` tag when you echo something. It's more flexible. [PHP Tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: The linked page says that `<?` is discouraged, because (in some versions at least) it depends on the short_open_tag ini setting. And it doesn't explain how `<?=` is supposed to be more flexible than `<?php echo`.

Comment: @MrLister It is a lot easier than using <?php echo. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188397/why-are-echo-short-tags-permanently-enabled-as-of-php-5-4)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with jquery
In case somebody will need it in the future
Thank's everybody

```
    <?php do { ?>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
      $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
  });
  </script>
      <tr>
        <td width="60" align="left"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['et_paragogis']; ?></td>
        <td width="5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="30" align="right"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['movies']; ?></td>
        <td width="8">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="90" align="left"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['format']; ?></td>
      </tr>
```